# No property findEventsOnSearchCriteria found for type Event (PropertyReferenceException)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I use `spring-data` to create a repository. However, when I try to start the project, I got the following error:

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No
>   property findEventsOnSearchCriteria found for type Event!

The source code is shown as below.

EventRepository.java:

```
@Repository
public interface EventRepository extends CrudRepository<Event, String>, EventRepositoryCustom {
}
```

EventRepositoryCustom.java:

```
public interface EventRepositoryCustom { 
    Event findEventsOnSearchCriteria();
}
```

EventRepositoryCustomImpl.java:

```
public class EventRepositoryCustomImpl implements EventRepositoryCustom {
    @Override
    public Event findEventsOnSearchCriteria() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `EventRepositoryCustomImpl.java` class name with `EventRepositoryImpl.java`.

- Custom interface -> -Custom suffix to repository
- Implementation -> -Impl suffix to repository